# Identical JQuery function is working for one link, not another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#subbutton').click(function() {
            $('#subbutton').hide();

        });
    });
</script>
```

It simply makes this button hide when clicked:

```
 <a id="subbutton" class="button" href="javascript:TINY.box.show({url: 'follow',width:600,height:170,openjs:'initPopupLogin',opacity:30})"><span>Button</span></a>
```

Now, if i try to use the identical function, but with a link later on the page, it doesnt work (i have erased the original button at this point) Here is the code:

```
<div id="subbutton">
        <a href="#"><span>Button</span></a>
</div>
```

I have tried putting the id in the anchor and in the span, nothing seems to be working for this link. Any idea why this isn't working? (I have deleted the original button so that this second button is a unique id on the page)

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/Wv8xT/

Comment: What do you mean by 'erased the original button'? You cannot have duplicate id values in the same page.

Comment: That's what I mean by I erased it, I deleted the original button so that the id only exists for the second one

Comment: I think this is more in line with what he is saying http://jsfiddle.net/Wv8xT/2/. And like everyone's said, you can't have duplicate ids...

Comment: Jimmy at the time the event is bound, the event is only bound for the first button with that id (since id's are unique, jquery only binds it to the first element with that id) on the page. When you later delete that button the other button doesn't have any event handlers attached to it. Why not use a class instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead to attach your event handler. I am suspecting the button is not in the dom at the time you attach the event handler.

```
$(document).on('click', '#subbutton', function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

EDIT now that i understand the problem. You are better off giving the buttons a class and using a class selector.

Answer (score 1):

`.hide` doesn't remove the element from the page so your selector will still be matching on the first element. You need to use `.remove` to remove the first element from the DOM so the second selector can work.

Also,  little jQuery optimization. The nested call to $('#subbutton') is not needed. At best, it is harder to maintain, at worst, it could cause performance issues if you put this in a large loop. This is better.

```
$(function() {
    $('#subbutton').click(function() {
        $(this).remove();

    });
});
```

Comment: ah interesting, didnt realize you could do that with the "this"

Comment: In jQuery, `this` is always bound to the dom element that threw the event. It's pretty useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a " after this:

```
<a id="subbutton" class="button
```

and Id has to be unique. Then it should work.

Comment: Sorry it is unique, I deleted the original button so that the second one was the only on the page, I should have explained that clearer.

Comment: I tested in Firefox and IE and it works - as long as the link (I mean the div, the last one) is the only one. Before I tested with both links and it didn't work because of the missing " in the first one and also the id

Answer (score 0):

Don't reuse ids, they must be unique. pass the id to the function

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to:

```
 $(function() {
        $('#subbutton').live("click",function() {
          $(this).hide();
        });
    });​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2agx/

- also don't reuse id's. use a class for multiple DOM elements that you want to be able to select together.

Comment: Live has been deprecated, use .on instead.

Comment: `live` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7 - use `on` instead, as `live` just points to that. (See http://tutsplus.com/lesson/bind-live-delegate-huh/, it's a great series).